# Powershell csom error : Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I'm tring to get the file by relative URL . I"m usig sharepoint onligne 
.
and i get this error:

> Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl

here is the code:

```
$web = $ctx.Web
  $ctx.Load($web)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  $PageLayoutName = $pageLayoutContentType
  $items = $web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($PageLayoutName)
  $ctx.Load($items)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: what values are you using in `$pageLayoutContentType` and `$PageLayoutName` ?  It needs to be relative url like `/sites/test/_catalogs/master/mypagelayout.aspx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check a page layout server relative url with Rest API, for example, get a pagelayout server relative url in Pages Library:

```
http://sp/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items(1)/file
```

[image]

And use this value in $web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl method